# Calculation more than 24 hours in SQL Server 2008

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have multiple records as workinghours of employee as

```
02:10:00
03:00:00
12:00:00
12:34:56
```

Now i need to add these record and want to display in

```
`hh:mm:ss`
```

Format. I used following query but it only works when sum of record less than 24 hours but record may be greater than 24 hours.

```
SELECT CAST(DATEADD(MILLISECOND, 
               SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '00:00:00.000'
         , CAST(WorkHrs AS TIME))), '00:00:00.000') AS TIME) AS Total_Time
FROM tblAttend
```

I spend more than 4 hours on google to find solution but got no success anymore.

Datatype of workinghour column is varchar .

Comment: Can you give an example of a WorkHrs record greater than 24 hours?

Comment: First of all, do not store dates/time related information as `VARCHAR`. Try `TIME` or `DATETIME`.

Comment: @Max, Sorry for my late respond due to my internet connection down. Working hours are not greater than 24 hrs but its sum will be greater than 24 hrs.

Answer (score 2):

The time data type has an explicit range only up to 24 hours (see [here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb677243.aspx)).

So, I think you are basically stuck with doing the conversion yourself.  It is ugly, but looks something like:

```
SELECT RIGHT('00' + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '00:00:00.000', CAST(WorkHrs AS TIME))), '00:00:00.000')/(60*60) AS VARCHAR(255)), 2)
            ) + 
       RIGHT('00' + CAST((SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '00:00:00.000', CAST(WorkHrs AS TIME))), '00:00:00.000')/60 % 60) AS VARCHAR(255)), 2) +
       RIGHT('00' + CAST(SUM(DATEDIFF(MILLISECOND, '00:00:00.000', CAST(WorkHrs AS TIME))), '00:00:00.000') % 60 AS VARCHAR(255)), 2)
            )
```

Comment: What would be a suitable datatype or method to store this kind of information for easy access? A single `seconds` or `milliseconds` column or 4 columns with `hour`, `minute`, `second`, `millisecond`?

Comment: @RaduGheorghiu . . . I think an integer storing seconds would be my preference for the data type.

Answer (score 1):

Merhaba Waqas,

Could you please try following SQL CTE Select statement,
It returns hours value more than 24, for this case it was 29 I guess.
Please check [time calculation on SQL Server](http://www.kodyaz.com/t-sql/calculate-time-operations-in-sql-server.aspx), this select is adapted from there

```
;with cte as (
select
    userid,
    total = sum(  DATEPART(ss,period) + 60 * DATEPART(mi,period) + 3600 * DATEPART(hh,period) )
from WorkingHours
group by userid
)
select
    userid,
    total [Total Time in Seconds],
    (total / 3600) [Total Time Hour Part],
    ((total % 3600) / 60) [Total Time Minute Part],
    (total % 60) [Total Time Second Part] 
from cte
```

I hope it helps you

Comment: Sorry for late reply due to internet connection down. So your suggestion didn't work and give me same error that greater than 24 hrs are not accepted.